# Is it possible to install SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, windows-server

I suspect that SP2013 is not officially supported on top of Windows Server 2016, but I'm interested to install it in such scenario for testing purposes. It seems that prerequisites installer fails specifically because Application Server role has been deprecated in Windows Server 2016 (see this [question on serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/815025/how-to-install-application-server-role-on-windows-server-2016)). Anyone with positive experience of getting SP2013 to work on top of Server 2016? Is it possible at all? NOTE: I'm not asking about official supportability (I guess it is not supported configuration), but about practical feasibility of doing this.

Comment: [Install SharePoint Foundation 2013 on Windows Server 2016 Solution](http://roger.dilsner.com/install-sharepoint-foundation-2013-windows-server-2016-solution/)

Comment: I resolved this problem following this Microsoft Link https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3087184/sharepoint-2013-or-project-server-2013-setup-error-if-the--net-framewo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible as certain Windows Server role/feature installation methods have changed.

Comment: My attempts confirm this and according to MSFT statement from 2017-01-05: "At this time, Windows Server 2016 RTM is not supported." (source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx). Wondering if this will change or stay permanently "at this time" :)

Comment: It will be permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to install Foundation 2013 onto Windows 2016 server, and Windows 2012 server, both with SQL 2016. So far, the installation including prerequisities was successful after some workarounds (installing prereq to 2016 according this http://yamanxworld.blogspot.cz/2016/11/sharepoint-foundation-2013-and-windows.html), and doing that .net 4.6 thing (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3087184/sharepoint-2013-or-project-server-2013-setup-error-if-the-.net-framework-4.6-is-installed).
PSConfig went fine.
Now trying to deploy custom solutions.

Comment: Neither Server 2016 nor SQL 2016 are supported by any of the SharePoint 2013 products.

Comment: Not saying it is supported, but it is indeed possible. Already finished the deployment and running a farm including custom solutions.

Comment: That's kind of the problem with providing this as an 'answer'. Microsoft will not support such a deployment.

Comment: @TrevorSeward I would re-read the question. OP specifically mentioned that they accepted solutions not supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it posible with some change in installations files. You need to install prereq manual and download update for .net and put it install files.

In windows 2019 it isnt work. Only win 2016

Answer (score 0):

You can install SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2016:

http://win66.ru/microsoft/sharepoint/85-sharepoint-2013-windows-server-2016

Answer (score 0):

Yes It possible but some difficult you wait

https://sharepoint-ru.blogspot.com/2021/07/sharepoint-2013-windows-server-20162019.html